# How to take input in one line for array and its length in python

Tags: python, arrays, input

i want to take ***input*** as

```
3 10 20 30
```

i.e, n array elements

I tried -

```
n , arr = int(input()), list(map(int(input).split()[:n]))
```

It shows error as `n is not defined`

Comment: Seems like you are trying to solve a challenge on one of these competitive programming sites. Let me give you a hint: Due to Python being a dynamic language (in simple terms) you don't need to care about the length of the "incoming" input array. Just do `arr = list(map(int, input().split()))[1:]`

Comment: what is the expected output for `n` and `arr`?

Comment: n should be 3 and arr=[10,20,30]

Answer (score 2):

Think about how Python interprets your statement:

1. it evaluates the r-value (the right-hand-side part of the assignment), which is a `tuple`, then
2. assigns that `tuple` to the l-value: `(n, arr)`.

But in step 1, it encounters a yet-unknown quantity: `n`.

You would therefore do, instead (and assuming `s = '3 10 20 30'`, as it isn't a good idea to shadow the built-in function `input()`):

```py
arr = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
n = len(arr)  # if you really need it
```

**Edit**

It has been pointed out that the expected result may be `n: 3` and `arr: [10, 20, 30]`. If that is indeed the case:

```py
n, *arr = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output. If `s = '3 10 20 30'` then OP wants `n = 3, arr = [10, 20, 30]`

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but I can see that would be a plausible way to interpret it.

Comment: asterisk tuple packing/unpacking of your edit is the best solution, if you need to check `n` against the number of elements after that.

Comment: you should keep your answer as well: it's fun to see the walrus operator in action!

Comment: Yes, but in this case it's overkill and very hard to read. So far the only "useful" cases of assignment expressions I have found are conditionals.

Comment: it helps thnk u

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3.8+ this can be solved quite elegantly by using assignment expressions:

```
n, arr = int((v := input().split())[0]), list(map(int, v[1:]))
```

[Obviously, you can just calculate n after the splitting and mapping as well, making the code much easier to read.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492365/1170207)

Comment: Nice! but I believe OP meant to `len(v := input().split()[1:]), list(map(int, v))`

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.